# Flutter - How to maintain _isExpanded status of ExpansionTiles list after deleting an element?

Tags: listview, dart, flutter

The question is about the [Flutter](https://www.flutter.io) framework.

I have built a list of ExpansionTiles using the ListView.builder function. When opening an ExpansionTile and then deleting it, the other ExpansionTiles move up in the list as expected. However, now the ExpansionTile that replaces the deleted ExpansionTile is unfolded. Here is a [animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUD2k.gif) showing that problem. The question now is, how do I get it working that the replacing ExpansionTile keeps its status from before.

Here is the source code to the problem.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: ItemList(),
    );
  }
}

class ItemList extends StatefulWidget {
  ItemList({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ItemListState createState() => _ItemListState();
}

class _ItemListState extends State<ItemList> {
  List<String> items;
  List<int> ids;
  List<Widget> widgetItem;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    items = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4', 'Item 5'];
    ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: items.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return ExpansionTile(
            title: Text('Title'),
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(items[index]),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                    onPressed: () => setState(() => items.removeAt(index)),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can also use the values in `items` as value for the `ValueKey` if they are unique, then you don't need to delete from `items` **and** `ids`. I wasn't 100% what `ids` was for in your example.

Comment: Good idea to use the items directly as keys and now that you say it, the IDs are really superfluous for the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just ensure the items have an unique key so that Flutter can recognize the new `ExpansionTile` at the deleted index is a different one

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: ItemList(),
    );
  }
}

class ItemList extends StatefulWidget {
  ItemList({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ItemListState createState() => _ItemListState();
}

class _ItemListState extends State<ItemList> {
  List<String> items;
  List<int> ids;
  List<Widget> widgetItem;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    items = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4', 'Item 5'];
    ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: items.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return ExpansionTile(
            key: ValueKey('${ids[index]}'),
            title: Text('Title'),
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(items[index]),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                    onPressed: () => setState(() {
                          items.removeAt(index);
                          ids.removeAt(index);
                        }),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

See also https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn0EOS-ZiIc